# unset gives array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having an `ID` from `GET` and checking if that `ID` is in a `custom field` and if so, place a **remove button** otherwise display an `add button`

The `custom field` gets a `string` each time we send the value but in order to remove it, I use `unset` in the array while checking if the `current ID` is there or not.

Getting really confused as I am mixing `implode` and `explode`

Whole code:

```
$postId = $_GET['postId'];
$allposts = '';
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$userPosts = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post', TRUE );
$userPosts = explode(',', $userPosts);
$response = wp_remote_get('https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?include='.$postId);
if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
    return;
}
$posts = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );
if ( empty( $posts ) ) {
    return;
}
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    if (isset($_POST['save_post'])) {
        array_push($userPosts, $postId);
        $userPosts = array_values(array_unique($userPosts));
        $userPosts = implode(',', $userPosts);
        $userPosts = trim($userPosts);
        $userPosts = ltrim($userPosts, ",");
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post', $userPosts );
    }
    if (isset($_POST['remove_post'])) {
        if (($key = array_search($postId, $userPosts)) !== false) {
            unset($userPosts[$key]);
        }
        $userPosts = implode(',', $userPosts);
        $userPosts = trim($userPosts);
        $userPosts = ltrim($userPosts, ",");
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post', $userPosts );
    }
}
if ( ! empty( $posts ) ) {
    // For each post.
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        $allposts .= '<a href="' . esc_url( $post->link ) . '" target=\"_blank\">' . esc_html( $post->title->rendered ) . '</a>  ' . esc_html( $fordate ) . '<br />'.$post->content->rendered;
    ?>
    <div class="container margin-top-80 margin-bottom-80">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8">
                <form id="savedPosts" action="" method="POST" class="" autocomplete="off">
                    <input type="hidden" name="save_post" value="<?php echo $postId; ?>"> 
                    <?php
                        $userPosts = implode(',', $userPosts);
                        if (strpos($userPosts, $postId) !== false) { ?>
                                <button disabled="disabled" type="submit" class="save_post disabled btn btn-outline-dark" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="già nei tuoi favoriti">Già nella box</button>
                                <button id="remove_post" name="remove_post" type="submit" class="save_post" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="aggiungilo alla tua box">Rimuovi dalla box</button>
                            <?php } else {   
                            ?>
                                <button id="save_post" name="save_post" type="submit" class="save_post" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="aggiungilo alla tua box">Salva nella box</button>
                        <?php  }
                    ?>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php }
}
?>
```

Comment: As the error state, you should pass 2nd parameter an array `array_search(value, $arr)`

Comment: try var_dump($userPosts) before array_search and see what you have

Comment: @RakeshJakhar indeed but if I do `$userPosts = explode(',', $userPosts);` just before `if (($key = array_search($postId, $userPosts)) !== false) {` then I will have a different but similar error with `if (strpos($userPosts, $postId) !== false) {` literally getting confused and I am doing something very wrong with all those implode and explode

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro see my prev comment

Comment: write what is $userPosts before the explode (get_user_meta) and after it

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro what do you mean?

Comment: something like: var_dump($userPosts) after get_user_meta function call, and the same after explode function call

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro string(6) "128471" array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "128471" }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196185/discussion-between-rob-m-and-giacomo-masseroni-chiaro).

Comment: the only possible explanation for what's going on here , is that you are passing both of `save_post` and `remove_post` , make sure of it;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the get_user_meta returns an array, so no need to explode the response,
but if the response is empty it will be treated as string.

here you should change this line by :

> $userPosts = !empty(get_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post', TRUE )) ? get_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post', TRUE ): [];

Answer (score 0):

In the first implode for $userPosts it got converted to string which is comma separated and that is being used in the array_search which is causing the issue.
Rename the variable name to something other that userPosts while manipulating it.